# Splitting array values into the correct column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

Need some help on sorting the values into the correct column.
I can't seem to figure out how I would return the array values to the proper column in the table.

For the output into *column B* `"Pipe DN"` it should return the *first* **split text** from the values in `"Line number"`, and for the `"Service"` *column F* it should return the *2nd* split text from `"Line number"`.

How would I accomplish this? -
If for `"Pipe DN"` I use `Range("B19", Range("B19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 1)).Value = StrArray`, it will return me the correct values, but the `"Service"` code is not written on the correct column.
[image]

```vb
Sub SplitLinesIntoArray()
    
    Dim LineNumber() As Variant
    Dim StrArray() As Variant
    Dim Dimension1 As Long, Counter As Long
    
    LineNumber = Range("J19", Range("J19").End(xlDown))
    
    Dimension1 = UBound(LineNumber, 1)
    
    ReDim StrArray(1 To Dimension1, 1 To 2)
    
    For Counter = 1 To Dimension1
        'Pipe DN
        StrArray(Counter, 1) = Split(LineNumber(Counter, 1), "-")(0)
        Range("B19", Range("B19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = StrArray
        'Service Code
        StrArray(Counter, 2) = Split(LineNumber(Counter, 1), "-")(1)
        Range("F19", Range("F19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = StrArray(Counter, 2)
    Next Counter
    
    'Range("B19", Range("B19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 1)).Value = StrArray
    Erase LineNumber
    Erase StrArray
    
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much T.M. you have explained it very well and in detail. The only thing I haven't understand is the buildjagged procedure. Still trying to digest this information :)

Comment: You are welcome. - The procedure "tells" VBA: *"I got an already declared "naked" array container as argument (to which I'm able to point by reference), now I redimension it to the wanted indices of sub-arrays (i.e. 0 To 2) and fill "sub-division" 1 & 2 with a temporary "vertical" array where each is  sufficiently dimensioned to hold the 2-dimensional pipe and service data."* Thus JaggedArray(1) now is able to hold a complete 2-dim pipe array to be filled rowwise by the calling procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you start well by analyzing a 2-dim datafield array and assigning resulting string manipulations (`Split()`) to it.

Results *seem* to (1) output correctly as for the first array "column" ("Pipe DN", starting in cell `B19`),
whereas (2) the second column ("Service", `F19`)  repeats the result of the very last split action for each array "row".

This impression has to be qualified:

- ad 1) You are doing unnecessary extra work by assigning the **entire** `StrArray` to the entire "Pipe DN" column,
  repeating this action with each single row iteration. (Note that the `StrArray` gets only completely filled with the last loop).
- ad 2) Basically you assign again with each iteration, but this time you get only the latest split result and fill the entire "Service" column
  with the latest result assigned to `StrArray(Counter,2)`. Eventually all items show the last split result instead of the individual LineNumber splittings.

See this abbreviated example for three example items only to understand what is happening
(this SnapShot shows the table results when code is stopped after the 2nd iteration (i.e. after `Counter=2`):
[image: Illustrating example after 2nd iteration]

**Immediate help**

Sticking to your initial code, I'd **omit**

- `Range("B19", Range("B19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = StrArray` as well as
- `Range("F19", Range("F19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = StrArray(Counter, 2)`

within the `For`..`Next` loop, but **add** the following two code lines thereafter:

- `Range("B19", Range("B19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = Application.Index(StrArray, 0, 1)`
- `Range("F19", Range("F19").Offset(Dimension1 - 1, 0)).Value = Application.Index(StrArray, 0, 2)`

in order to **slice** the `StrArray` into columns and write each column separately to your cell target.

**Further note:**

**Fully qualify** your *range references* to prevent possibly unwanted results as Excel would take the currently active sheet if not referenced explicitly ... and this need not be the targeted one :-;

Using VBA, it's not necessary in standard office situations to clear (`Erase`) at the end of a procedure to free memory.

---

**Possible alternative avoiding array slicing**

You might profit from the the following code, which

- fully qualifies your range references (note: unqualified refs invite Excel to take the currently active sheet without request),
- uses a **jagged array** (*aka* as Array of Arrays) to avoid (multiple) **column slicing** (as needed in OP)
- demonstrates the use of Private **Const**ants on module top (used here for enumerating the sub-arrays within the jagged array
- demonstrates a *help procedure* to provide for a correcty dimensioned jagged array:

**Example code**

```
Option Explicit                     ' declaration head of code module (forching variable declarations)

Private Const LineNum As Long = 0   ' enumerate sub-arrays within jagged array 
Private Const Pipe    As Long = 1
Private Const Service As Long = 2
```

```
Sub SplitLinesIntoJaggedArray()
'I. Set Worksheet object to memory               ' fully qualify any range references!
    Dim ws As Worksheet                          ' declare ws as of worksheet object type
    Set ws = Tabelle1                            ' << use the project's sheet Code(Name)
    'set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' or: via a sheet's tabular name (needn't be the same)

With ws                                          ' With .. End With structure, note the following "."-prefixes
'II.Definitions
'a) assign target start cell addresses to array tgt
    Dim tgt As Variant
    tgt = Split("J19,B19,F19", ",")              ' split requires "Dim tgt" without brackets to avoid Error 13
'b) define source range object and set to memory
'   Note: tgt(LinNum) equalling tgt(0) equalling "J19"
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = .Range(tgt(LineNum), .Range(tgt(0)).End(xlDown))   ' showing both enumerations only for demo:-)
    Dim CountOfRows As Long: CountOfRows = src.Rows.Count        ' count rows in source range
'c) provide for a correctly dimensioned jagged array to hold all 2-dim data arrays (three columns)
    Dim JaggedArray() As Variant
    BuildJagged JaggedArray, CountOfRows     ' << call help procedure BuildJaggedArray

'III.Assign column data to JaggedArray
'a) assign LineNum column as 2-dim datafield to JaggedArray(LineNum)
    JaggedArray(LineNum) = src.Value
'b) assign LineNum splits to JaggedArray(Pipe) and JaggedArray(Service)
    Dim Counter As Long
    For Counter = 1 To CountOfRows
    '1. Pipe DN
        JaggedArray(Pipe)(Counter, 1) = Split(JaggedArray(LineNum)(Counter, 1), "-")(0)
    '2. Service Code
        JaggedArray(Service)(Counter, 1) = Split(JaggedArray(LineNum)(Counter, 1), "-")(1)
    Next Counter
        
'IV.Write result columns of jagged array to target addresses
'   Note: tgt(Pipe)=tgt(1)="B19", tgt(Service)=tgt(2)="F19"
    Dim elem As Long
    For elem = Pipe To Service
        .Range(tgt(elem)).Resize(CountOfRows, 1) = JaggedArray(elem)
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

***Help procedure `BuildJagged`**

Note that the first procedure argument passes the jagged array **By** **Ref**erence (=default, if not explicitly passed `ByVal`).
This means that any further actions within the help procedure have an immediate effect on the original array.

```
Sub BuildJagged(ByRef JaggedArray, ByVal CountOfRows As Long)
'Purpose: provide for correct dimensions of the jagged array passed By Reference
        ReDim JaggedArray(LineNum To Service)   ' include LineNum as data base (gets dimmed later)
        Dim tmp() As Variant
        ReDim tmp(1 To CountOfRows, 1 To 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = Pipe To Service                 ' suffices here to start from 1=Pipe to 2=Service
            JaggedArray(i) = tmp
        Next i
End Sub
```

**Further link**

[Error in finding last used cell in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Comment: Sorry mate for the late actions, I'm just new and still getting to know how it works here.  How do I add you as new user? @T.M.